# Shrink filename (remove last N columns)

Tags: linux, unix, mv, cut

I want to remove from this filename last 3 columns

```
david@david-ThinkPad-E480:~/Downloads$ ll A*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 david david 16006720 сен  9 11:03 'A.Matrosov. E.Rodionov. S.Bratus. Rootkits and Bootkits. Reversing Modern Malware and Next Gen...pdf'
david@david-ThinkPad-E480:~/Downloads$
```

I tried

```
david@david-ThinkPad-E480:~/Downloads$ mv A.Matrosov.\ E.Rodionov.\ S.Bratus.\ Rootkits\ and\ Bootkits.\ Reversing\ Modern\ Malware\ and\ Next\ Gen...pdf {cut -d ' ' -f 1-6 <<< ls A.Matrosov.\ E.Rodionov.\ S.Bratus.\ Rootkits\ and\ Bootkits.\ Reversing\ Modern\ Malware\ and\ Next\ Gen...pdf}
```

Comment: What's a "column" in your context? Is it a character (so you want to remove the trailing `pdf`)? It would help if you showed your intended filename so we can see by example what you want removed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, using shell parameter expansion (assuming the name is in `$fn`)

```
ext=${fn##*.}        # get extension
noext=${fn%.*}       # shed extension
minus1=${noext%.*}   # shed last part
minus2=${minus1%.*}  # shed next to last part
minus3=${minus2%.*}  # etc...
final=${minus3}.${ext}
```

Writing this as an unreadable one-liner is left as a exercise for the reader :)

With `perl-rename` (aka `rename` or `prename`, depending on distro):

```
rename 's/^(.*)(\.[^.]+){3}(\.[^.]+)$/$1$3/' <file>
```

(remove `-n` or replace by `-v` for actual execution).